# {% request.user ==" "%} Checking User and rendering html element with if else Django Templatetag

Tags: python, django

Html code:

```
            {% if request.user== "Sangam" %}
                <li class=""> <a class="text-left " href="landscapes.html" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false"><i class="flaticon-bar-chart-1"></i> Landscape </a>
                </li>
             {% endif %} 

             {% if request.user  == "Sam" %}
            <li class=""> <a class="text-left " href="characters.html" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"><i class="flaticon-bar-chart-1"></i> Characters </a>
            </li>
             {% endif %}
```

I want to do is if the user is Sangam then render a  certain html element for him only.
But,It doesn't render so. Can I do this?.Also,I wonder how can we render certain html elements to users that we have list him/her to a certain Group in Django-admin panel

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare the `.username` of the logged in user:

```
{% if request.user.username == "Sangam" %}
    <li class=""> <a class="text-left " href="landscapes.html" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="flaticon-bar-chart-1"></i> Landscape </a></li>
{% endif %}

{% if request.user.username == "Sam" %}
    <li class=""><a class="text-left " href="characters.html" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="flaticon-bar-chart-1"></i> Characters </a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you It worked!.Can i ask another question? what if i want to render html elements in the same way checking if the user falls on the particular groups that i defined in django admin using template tag?